# unable to connect django and angular 2

Tags: python, django, angular

I want to connect my angular 2 app to django but how can i connect because both have different servers. I also read about cors but didn't work. Please suggest me some simple way to connect both of them

> views.py

```
# Home Page
def index(request):
return render(request, "index.html")
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

> .angular-cli.json

```
"root": "src",
  "outDir": "../userRecord/templates",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
```

***userRecord is Django Server***

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1):

Hello I found a GitHub Repo without any Error

Here I posting the URL of that repo

https://github.com/badcoder28/djangular2

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem serving the django backend and the angular frontend from different domains, but you do have to set up CORS correctly for it to work.

To configure that, you'll have to setup Django to return the CORS headers and allow the domain where your frontend lives. These might be helpful:

https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve angular app using django server.

In order to do this you need to keep angular bundled file in django static directory.

If you are using angular cli then you need to change **outDir: "../../static/app"** property in .angular-cli.json file to your django static directory, so whenever you build your app, your compiled file will be in django static directory.

Refer these static files into your django html page which django serve whenever you launch your app.

**Happy Coding**

**EDIT**

In urls.py you can configure like this

> urlpatterns = [
>       url(r'^', views.index, name='index')
>   ]

In your views.py have the index action like this.

> def index(request):
>
> return render(request, "your template path")

Make sure your def index action should return index.html.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: its mean when i run ng build then files are created in django static folder instead of dist

Comment: Yeah, you are right. dist is a default folder name.

Comment: i tried this but there is one problem with that... i make template folder of django is outdir.... when i run ng build command then its display index.html and other bundled file in templates folder of django but when i type npm start command then templates folder automatically delete.. Please help to solve this issue.... Thanks for Reply

Comment: You need to run django server because that will be your server.??

Comment: I also start django server but say template doesn't exists because when i run **npm start** command then automatically template folder delete which generate by **ng build** _Thanks for Reply_

Comment: You don't have to run npm start. You need to run django server i.e. python manage.py runserver <your ip>. Use index.html in default view. I hope you have configured your urls.py file properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159682/discussion-between-jyotiraditya-parmar-and-shubham-kandiyal).

Comment: I also do this, then give error 404 error file not found app.component.ts file not found... may be this error is occur because of I do not start  angular 2 server...  **Thanks for Reply**

Comment: hello, its angular 2 not 1, there is no js file, only ts file... please describe file structure for whole app... **Thanks for Reply**

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, please tell me whats i do wrong... **Thanks for update Answer**

Comment: When you run django server and open it in browser, are you getting this index.html page..?? if yes then other files should come along with it. If other bundle files are not loading then you have to change script tag src attribute value in index.html because now your root directory is django server. Could you please tell me the bundled js files path..???